# Wifi Problem in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, realtek

When I boot Ubuntu 14.04, Wifi works properly for few minutes, but after that I can't connect to internet.But still my Wifi status shows connected.

**lshw**

```
 - *-network

     - description: Wireless interface
               product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
               vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
               physical id: 0
               bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
               logical name: wlan0
               version: 00
               serial: ac:b5:7d:20:cd:e4
               width: 64 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
               configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.1.6-040106-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.142
    latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
               resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0c00000-f0c03fff
```

**lspci**

- Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
- Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

**lspci -vvnn**

- Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)

  - Kernel driver in use: r8169
- Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

  - Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be